# Can I set a Packer provisioner attribute only if a var is provided?

Tags: ansible, packer, amazon-ami

I'm using the [AWS builder](https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/integrations/hashicorp/amazon/latest/components/builder/ebs) and [Ansible provisioner](https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/integrations/hashicorp/ansible). If I packer a `-var app_version=latest`, I'd like to add the key and value as an AWS tag and/or pass to Ansible as an `--extra-vars`.

If no value is passed, there should be no tag or `extra-vars`.

I tried defining

```
variable "app_version" {
  type    = string
  default = ""
}
```

But that predictably ends up creating a tag with an empty value. I'd rather there be no tag at all if no value is set.

Is that possible?